# Trouble in using forEach function in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, foreach, mongoose

I have been learning about q promises and tried to build up some mock APIs to implement its functionality,While doing so I came across the following error,

> Enterprise.forEach is not a function

My API code is as follows,

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Enterprise = mongoose.model('Enterprise_gpy');
var q = require('q');

var displayEnterprise = function(req, res) {

  function displayEnterpriseName() {

    var deferred = q.defer();

    Enterprise.forEach(function(err, doc) {

      if (err) {
        console.log('Error Finding Files');
        deferred.reject(err);
      } else {
        var name = Enterprise.enterprise_name;

        deferred.resolve({
          name: name
        });
      }

      return deferred.promise;
    });
  }

  function displayEnterpriseEmail() {


    var deferred = q.defer();

    Enterprise.forEach(function(err, doc) {

      if (err) {
        console.log('Error Finding Files');
        deferred.reject(err);
      } else {
        var email = Enterprise.enterprise_email;

        deferred.resolve({
          email: email
        });
      }

      return deferred.promise;
    });
  }
  q.all([
      displayEnterpriseName(),
      displayEnterpriseEmail()
    ])
    .then(function(success) {
      console.log(500, success);
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
      console.log(200, err);
    });
}
module.exports = {

  displayEnterprise: displayEnterprise
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `Enterprise` is a mongoose schema so when you try to do loop using forEach then got

> Enterprise.forEach is not a function

you can use `forEach` after `Enterprise.find()`. so use

```
Enterprise.find({}, function(err, docs) {
   if (err) {
    console.log('Error Finding Files');
    deferred.reject(err);
   } else {
     var names = [];
     docs.forEach (function(doc) {
       var name = doc.enterprise_name;
       names.push(name);// pushed in names array
       //.....
     });
     deferred.resolve({
      names: names
    }); // return all names
   }
});
```

instead of

```
Enterprise.find().forEach
```

and should use

`var name = doc.enterprise_name;` instead of `var name = Enterprise.enterprise_name;`

and

`var email = doc.enterprise_email;` instead of `var email = Enterprise.enterprise_email;`

Comment: error persists, TypeError: Enterprise.find(...).forEach is not a function

Comment: well it works ,but displays only the first document name and email instead of   listing the entire documents in the Enterprise collection

Comment: your question was problem in `forEach` so I shown that. however if you want to return *all docs name* then *pushed in an array* and return it. see update answer :) @Idlliofrio

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` only works for arrays, and you're using it on a mongoose model.
try this instead:

```
Enterprise.find().exec(function(err, docs) {
  docs.forEach(function(doc) {
    // do something with all the documents
  }
  // do something outside the loop
})
```